# etoolbox : hook before code

Tags: etoolbox

Is there a way to make hook work before code?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}
    
\hhh % this does not work

foo

\appto\hhh{test1}

bar

\hhh % this work

\end{document}
```

Comment: It's a bit unclear: what do you mean by “before code”? I order that the first call to `\hhh` works you need to define it.

Comment: @egreg I need a result at the end of the article to be placed at the beginning of the text (like label and ref).

Comment: The result of what?

Comment: The result of the sum of two numbers (like \fpeval{2+3})

Comment: Sorry, but it's too vague. Can you give more context, please?

Comment: @polyn You need to tell how the numbers are obtained.

Comment: The number I want to display at the beginning is the distance of two points on a graph in tikz. The two points are intersections of two functions. When there is a change in the data, the final result changes and I want it to change at the same time at the beginning of the article.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store values in the `aux` file and recall them from there.

```
\documentclass{article}
% \setaux{var}{val} sets variable var to val
\newcommand\setaux[2]{\expandafter\xdef\csname aux#1\endcsname{#2}}
% \useaux{var} expands to the value of var
\newcommand\useaux[1]{\ifcsname aux#1\endcsname\csname aux#1\endcsname\else ???\fi}
\makeatletter
% \saveaux{var}{val} sets variable var to val and saves it also to the aux file
% such that the value is available anywhere in the document (after the next run).
\newcommand\saveaux[2]{%
  \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\setaux{#1}{#2}}%
  \setaux{#1}{#2}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
    
\useaux{hhh}

foo

\saveaux{hhh}{test1}

bar

\useaux{hhh}
\end{document}
```

After the first run, you get

```
???
foo
bar
test1
```

After the second run, you get

```
test1
foo
bar
test1
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much.